# Bootstrap table plugin not working in 'rtl' table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with [Arabic bootstrap](http://zerox.me/projects/bootstrap3/) for `rtl` support . I have a table and Bootstrap table plugin.

HTML :

```
<table class="bootstrap-table" id="listComments">
    <tr>
        <th data-fixed="right">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
        </th>
        <th class="text-right">Title</th>
        <th style="width: 200px">Category</th>
        <th style="width: 140px">Created date</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Status</th>
        <th data-fixed="left">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="itemCheckBox" value="6" />
            <input type="hidden" name="token[6]" value="b8c5b7b3584268c8a85f1a14c34699dd" />
        </td>
        <td>2323</td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td>09-19-2014</td>
        <td> <a href="" class="label label-success">Published</a> 
        </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="" title="Edit post"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmationDelete" href="" title="Delete post"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I designed my table with bootstrap table plugin. Plugin works using: `data-fixed="right"` or `data-fixed="left"`. With `data left` and `normal` this works fine. But in Arabic Bootstrap and  `data right` , this plugin is not working and shows horizontal scroll and displaced border.

how can I fix this for rtl table?

DEMO RTL NOT WORK : [JSFIIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xsoo79c5/)

DEMO NORMAL LTR WORK : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xsoo79c5/1/)

Screenshot in FF last version: (SEE scroll and right border Displaced for status and create date..)
[image]

Comment: i don't see a horizontal scroll bar or displaced border in your jsfiddle, can you maybe provide a screen shot?

Comment: @webeno: I add screenshot in FF.

Comment: think the whole mixup comes from the fact that you're using `data-fixed="right"` instead of actually leaving everything as is and only use `class="text-right"` which is the only thing you should normally need. That we you don't have to reverse order your menus and all should be alligned correctly... not sure about the bottom scroll in FF, might be something specific to FF...

Comment: @webeno: `class="text-right"` not a important class. we can remove this.

Comment: no, i meant the other way around, actually, i think you're better off using normal table than rtl... i've never used it but it specifies 'last-child' not to have a right border, however in rtl it will be the first one which obviously doesn't make sense... i suggest to get rid of the reversed table layout, just use the standard one, and add `class="text-right"` wherever needed...

Comment: @webeno: can add your code mind into jsfiddle?! in left of check box I see two overlap border. this border should between status and create date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62075/discussion-between-webeno-and-).

Comment: As a wild guess, remember that Arabic text is processed right-to-left, while Western languages are processed left-to-right.  Perhaps a right-to-left re-design of your data-presentation layout will fix the right-border problem (is your current layout in the most-appropriate presentation order for someone expecting to start seeing data at the right margin?).  I don't have any suggestion about the scroll bar, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your problem isn't really complex, I think that using classes for your `td` elements would have help you a lot, and I strongly encourage you to use them for this and any other project.

Now, for your solution, simply add this couple lines in your CSS style sheet:

```
.table-scroll .table-body td:first-child {
    border-right:none
}
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Of course, it will be a lot better if you use something like `.table.tableRtl td{....}` so you can target elements properly and more accurately while letting you use the `.table` class in other instance(s), but as long as your code goes, this CSS will work.

**EDIT**

there's an issue with one of the columns not having border. This happens because you have this line in bootstrap-table.css

```
.table-scroll .table-body td:last-child {
    border-right: medium none;
}
```

so basically it overrides all borders it has declared previously telling "in the last column, we should have no borders". But in [rtl direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction), the last column is in fact VISUALLY the first, so we fix it like this:

```
.table-scroll .table-body td:last-child, .table-scroll .table-header th:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

And now it all works as expected, with columns keeping the width as well, and borders behaving as expected

[Check CSS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy9dgy9n/)

Comment: You Right. Your Code Remove and fix scroll but I have border Between Created date and status. I cant see this?! Why?

Comment: fiddle link has changed as well, so be sure to check

Comment: perfect answer and perfect explanation, it also works way better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by webeno, the problem seems to be that `bootstrap-table.css` applies these rules:

```
.table-scroll .table-header th:last-child{
    border-right:none;
}
.table-scroll .table-body td:last-child{
    border-right:none;
}
```

This is in order to get rid of doubled borders on the rightmost edge of the table; in RTL, the `:last-child` is actually on the left though, which is why `status` has no right border. I overrode those styles with rules like this:

```
.table-scroll .table-header th:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
}
.table-scroll .table-body td:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
}
.table-scroll .table-header th:first-child {
    border-right:none;
}
.table-scroll .table-body td:first-child {
    border-right:none;
}
```

I also got rid of the `data-fixed="right"` attributes. Here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xsoo79c5/5/ .